# Bitcoin 2 of 4 Multisig script with one required

Tags: script, multi-signature

Hi I am to write a bitcoin locking script with property that 2 out of 4 signatures should be verified, but among those verified 2 there is a specific signature that should be verified.

I.e only 1 manager combined with 1 employee in a 4 employee company(including manager) can unlock the script, but the order of the signatures in unlocking script should not be important.
I have given a lot of thought to it, but was unable to satisfy the property that order doesnt matter in unlocking script. Could you please help me?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin script does not let you require a specific signature, however you could give the person that is required to have a specific signature additional keys and change it to a 4 of 6.

Manager has 3 keys.
Employee 1 has 1 key.
Employee 2 has 1 key.
Employee 3 has 1 key.

With 4 signatures required to spend the Manager only needs one employee present to sign, however the 3 employees can not produce a fully signed transaction without the Manager present as their 3 keys combined does not meet the 4 minimum required.